# Adding an If/Else statement within PHP foreach loop - WordPress Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, custom-fields

I have this WordPress Custom Field PHP Loop:

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
?>

    <a href="<?php echo $field['image-upload']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $field['image-url']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    <?php echo $field['image-description']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

And want to add an If/Else statement, like (this doesn't work):

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
?>

    if ( $field['image-upload'] ) {
        <a href="<?php echo $field['image-upload']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    }
    else {
        <a href="<?php echo $field['image-url']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    }
    <?php echo $field['image-description']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I've found that this works

```
<?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if ( $field['image-upload'] ) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $field['image-upload']; ?>">Go To Store!</a>
        <?php
        } else {
            echo $field['image-url'];
        }
        echo $field['image-description'];
        }
?>
```

But I run into syntax errors with the above code when trying to add HTML.

Edit: Working solution, thanks crystal

```
    <?php
    $fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
    ?>

    <? foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
    <ul>
        <? if ( $field['image-upload'] ) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $field['image-upload'] ?>">Link to image</a>
        <? else : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $field['image-url'] ?>">Link to image</a>
        <? endif ?>
            <li><?= $field['image-description'] ?>
    </ul>
    <? endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML should be written in `echo` or outside of `<?php ... ?>` like so:

```
<?php
$fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
foreach ($fields as $field) {

    if ( $field['image-upload'] ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $field['image-upload']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $field['image-url']; ?>">Link to image</a>
    <?php
    }
    echo $field['image-description'];
}
?>
```

If using short_open_tag:

```
<?php
$fields = CFS()->get('image-field');
?>

<? foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
    <? if ( $field['image-upload'] ) : ?>
        <a href="<?= $field['image-upload'] ?>">Link to image</a>
    <? else : ?>
        <a href="<?= $field['image-url'] ?>">Link to image</a>
    <? endif ?>
    <?= $field['image-description'] ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! The short_open_tag version worked well for my use case. I forgot to mention that I intended to have the returned values placed in an unordered list. That is where I had ran into syntax issues.